# How to convert values to their index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array containing 1's and 0's:

```py
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I'd like to convert each 1 to the index in the subarray that it's occuring at, to get this:

```py
e = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9],
              [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
              [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0]])
```

So far what I've done is multiply the array by a range:

```py
a * np.arange(a.shape[0])
```

which is good, but I'm wondering if there's a better, simpler way to do it, like a single function call?

Comment: I think your method is the fastest, Is there a reason you are  looking for another solution?

Comment: Generally, performing vector-matrix multiplications is more efficient than any per-cell strategy. With other words, I am a fan of your current approach.

Comment: @eshirvana It seems to me like there should be a builtin solution, because this is probably a common problem...anyway, I was hoping there was some special function I'd never seen before.

Comment: is it not problematic that the first column loses the location of the nonzero values?

Comment: " because this is probably a common problem" I have to admit, my first reaction to the question was to wonder what practical problem it would actually solve to modify the array this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This modifies `a` in place:

```
In [4]: i, j = np.nonzero(a)

In [5]: a[i, j] = j

In [6]: a
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Make a copy if you don't want modify `a` in place.

Or, this creates a new array (in one line):

```
In [8]: np.arange(a.shape[1])[a]
Out[8]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: `a *= np.arange(...)` only requires a 1D array and works in place too.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is a fast as it gets but it uses the wrong dimension for the multiplication (it would fait if the matrix wasn't square).

Multiply the matrix by a range of **column** indexes:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

e = a * np.arange(a.shape[1])

print(e)
[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  5  0  7  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  1  2  0  0  0  6  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  2  0  0  5  0  0  0  9  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  5  0  0  0  9  0]
 [ 0  0  2  0  0  0  6  0  0  0 10]
 [ 0  0  0  3  0  0  6  0  8  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9  0]
 [ 0  1  2  0  0  5  6  0  0  0  0]]
```

Comment: Ah, good catch! That definitely wouldn't be good.

Comment: If you do `a *= np.arange(...)`, you could do it in-place

Answer (score 1):

I benchmarked the obligatory `np.einsum` approach, which was ~1.29x slower for larger arrays `(100_000, 1000)` than the corrected original solution. The inplace solution was ~8x slower than `np.einsum`.

```
np.einsum('ij,j->ij', a, np.arange(a.shape[1]))
```

Comment: I really don't like that I can't predict whether a calculation will benefit from `np.einsum`. For a slightly different task (elementwise matrix squaring), I measured ~1.10x faster computation using `np.einsum`.

Comment: Why community wiki?

Comment: @richardec - This is more of a "service" answer as better solutions were already available, but I figured future readers would test it anyway. And it was too long for a comment.